# SPAMfighter Exchange Module not integration

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

I have an issue with SPAMfighter Exchange Module after disabling SSLv3. Images weren't showing up and ASP errors when trying to login to the control panel. So I removed it, and reinstalled the application. No change, I'm getting some error messages that I hope can narrow down what's going on, but I'm trying to figure out the underlying cause of what killed SPAMfighter. When trying to integrate into exchange I get an error message that says

```
An error occured while saving credentials. This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.
```

I've read several things about FIPS but I can't seem to find anything that helps find a resolution for this.

I have this in my even viewer.

```
Failed to save admin audit log for this cmdlet invocation. 
Organization: First Organization 
Log content:
Cmdlet Name: New-ManagementRoleAssignment
Object Modified: SPAMfighter Service Account Impersonation
Parameter: Name = SPAMfighter Service Account Impersonation
Parameter: Role = ApplicationImpersonation
Parameter: User = cssd.local\SPAMfighterService
Caller: cssd.local/Users/Administrator
ExternalAccess: False
Succeeded: True
Run Date: 2015-07-23T18:51:13
OriginatingServer: CSSDVS1 (15.00.0847.030)

Error:
    Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.AuditLogAccessDeniedException: The requesting account doesn't have permission to access the audit log. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The requesting account does not have permission to serialize tokens. 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) 
at Microsoft.Exchange.SoapWebClient.EWS.ExchangeServiceBinding.GetFolder(GetFolderType GetFolder1) at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.EwsAuditClient.<>c__DisplayClass5.<CheckAndCreateWellKnownFolder>b__3() at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.EwsAuditClient.CallEwsWithRetries(Func`1 delegateEwsCall, Func`3 responseMessageProcessor)

 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.EwsAuditClient.CallEwsWithRetries(Func`1 delegateEwsCall, Func`3 responseMessageProcessor)
at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.EwsAuditClient.CheckAndCreateWellKnownFolder(DistinguishedFolderIdNameType parentFolder, DistinguishedFolderIdNameType targetFolder, FolderIdType& targetFolderId)
at Microsoft.Exchange.ProvisioningAgent.EwsAuditLogger.InitializeAdminAuditLogsFolder()
at Microsoft.Exchange.ProvisioningAgent.EwsAuditLogger..ctor(ExchangePrincipal principal)
at Microsoft.Exchange.ProvisioningAgent.AuditLoggerFactory.Create(ExchangePrincipal principal, ArbitrationMailboxStatus status)
at Microsoft.Exchange.ProvisioningAgent.ConfigWrapper.get_MailboxLogger()
at Microsoft.Exchange.ProvisioningAgent.AdminLogProvisioningHandler.WriteAuditRecord(Stopwatch stopwatch)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, I had to change the FIPS algorithm key to disable validated cryptographic algorithms.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FipsAlgorithmPolicy

Changed the value to 0